# Matlab: loop that plots optimal polynomial interpolation

Tags: matlab, loops, interpolation, matlab-figure

I am trying to write a loop that sorts through possible polynomial interpolation fits and then plots the interpolation with the smallest error value, s.norm value. Thus far, I have:

```
for i=1:10
    [p,S] = polyfit(x,y,i);
    f = polyval(p,x);
    subplot(5,2,i)
    plot(x,y,'*',x,f,'-')
    axis([0  3  -2.5  12])
    title(['Order is: ',num2str(i),' norm is: ',num2str(S.normr)])
end
```

This currently will plot all possible fits for polynomial of ith degree for $i={1, 2,..., 10}$ and will print the s.normr value with the graph. However, I want to change it so that the loop selects the interpolation with the smallest S.normr value and plots that. For this, I have the following so far:

```
for i=1:10
    [p,S] = polyfit(x,y,i);
    f = polyval(p,x);
    %fbest = polyval(p,x) if S.normr = min(S.normr) for i
    %subplot(1,1,i)
    %plot(x,y,'*',x,fbest,'-')
    axis([0  3  -2.5  12])
    title(['Order is: ',num2str(i),' norm is: ',num2str(S.normr)])
end
```

I've commented out the portion that I changed. I believe the logic is correct, but I'm not sure how to translate this to Matlab code.

The tricky part is that I don't want the loop to continue until it satisfies a designated criterion. Instead, I want it to continue through all n = 10 iterations, then select the iteration with the smallest S.normr as its output and then print this selection as a plot.

tl;dr: The first length of code works fine for plotting all possible interpolations. The issue is that I want to manipulate the code so that, instead of plotting all interpolations, it selects the interpolation with the smallest S.normr value and then plots that interpolation.

Comment: What exactly is the problem/what does nto work the way you want?

Comment: The first length of code works fine for the task described in that portion of my question. The issue is that I want to manipulate the code so that, instead of plotting all interpolations, it selects the interpolation with the smallest S.normr value and then plots that interpolation. I will add this into my question so that this is explicitly clear.

Comment: Then I recommend saving all the intermediate results, finding the one with the smallest `S.normr` and plotting it after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend saving all the intermediate results of the loop and then deciding which to plot *after* the for loop.

```
p = {}; %initialize cell array, as the polynomials have different lengths
for i=1:10
    [p{i},S] = polyfit(x,y,i);
    my_norm(i) = S.normr;
end
[~,k]=min(my_norm); %find the index of the minimum

f = polyval(p{k},x);
plot(x,y,'*',x,f,'-')
axis([0  3  -2.5  12])
title(['Order is: ',num2str(k),' norm is: ',num2str(my_norm(k))])
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much. Can you explain what you did here: [~,k]=min(norm); %find the index of the minimum

Comment: It seems that no matter what, it selects the polynomial of the highest order. Should that be happening?

Comment: Yes. As long as you have less degrees of freedom than constraints, a higher degree will result in a lower error. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29 `[m,k]=min(x)` calculates the minimum of `x`, stores the minimum in `m` and the position (index) of the minimum in `k`.